# is it possible to get the location of a phone using USSD?

Tags: ussd

Is there any way to get the location of a cell phone (i.e. latitude/longitude) automatically when the user starts a USSD session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that, talk to safaricom, its possible but I believe you have to convince them why they should allow you to get the location of a cell phone. For now they just provide 4 parameters as a response in USSD responses.